# URL illegal argument exception in java

Tags: java, url

I have an URL http://boss.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/07/10/today-in-small-business-pizza-for-everyone/ and I want to test whether this URL is reachable(i.e. I want to ping the URL) in java. This URL is working properly in the web-browser.

I also have this following code

```
  public boolean isReachable(String url) {
    if (url == null)
        return false;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);
        huc.connect();
        int code = 0;
        if (u.getHost() != null)
            code = huc.getResponseCode();   
        huc.disconnect();
        return (200 <= code && code <= 399);
    }catch(Exception ee) {
        System.out.println(ee);
        return false;
    }
```

When I execute this code I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null. I don't know why this happens and How can I verify this host is reachable ?

Comment: Have you debugged this code and verified the value of url before the URL constructor is invoked?

Comment: What do you get on `System.out.print(u.getHost());`?

Comment: `setFollowRedirects(false)` especially as 302 = REDIRECT is in the accepted range. Is faster and restricts the error search area. Try `http://blogs.nytimes.com/` and then subdomains etc. Maybe you must fake a browser with headers like User-Agent: ... .

Comment: Yes I have debugged and the value of url is correct. when I print It shows boss.blogs.nytimes.com(u.getHost())

Comment: But Joop Eggen, I want to verify this absolute URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page that you are checking returns 303 code, which means a redirection will occur, adding setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) to your HttpURLConnection instance should solve the problem.

Your code will be the following:

```
    public boolean isReachable(String url) {
       if (url == null)
           return false;
       try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        // HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true); REMOVE THIS LINE
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);
        huc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); // ADD THIS LINE
        huc.connect();
        int code = 0;
        if (u.getHost() != null)
            code = huc.getResponseCode();   
        huc.disconnect();
        return (200 <= code && code <= 399);
        }catch(Exception ee) {
        System.out.println(ee);
        return false;
        }
    }
```